# One function does not work inside another in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two functions which I run with a button:

```
this.state = {
      myLimit: this.props.limit.lim,
      modalOpen: false,
    }
submit = () => {
    // this sends state to Redux reducer 
    let lim = {'lim':this.state.myLimit};
    this.props.updateLimit(lim);

    // this sends update state for toggle in Parent component
    this.props.changeToggle(false);
// function open Modal for 1,5 second like "Success"
showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: true
    });
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        modalOpen: false
      })
    }, 1500);
  }

render(){   
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       //some code
        <Button onPress={ this.submit } onPressIn={ this.showModal } title='submit' />  
       <MyPopup visible={this.state.modalOpen}>
          <View style={styles.modal}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>The limit successfully changed</Text>
          </View>
        </MyPopup>  
      </View> 
    )
  }
```

Parent component

```
//Parent component 
...
    this.state = {
      openLimit: false,
    }

  toggle(toggler) {
    let togglerStatus = this.state[toggler]; 
    this.setState({
      [toggler]: !togglerStatus 
    });
  }

  // run changing toggle from child 'Limit'
  changeToggle = (val) => {
    console.log(val)
    this.setState({
      openLimit: val
    })
  };
return(
//some code
<Child changeToggle={this.changeToggle}/>
)
```

It works, but not always good enough. Sometimes the submit function does not send state to Redux reducer in this `this.props.updateLimit(lim)` and/or not change toggle state this `this.props.changeToggle(false)`.

So I am tried to combine it in one function:

```
combineFunc = () => {
 // this works
 // this sends state to Redux reducer 
    let lim = {'lim':this.state.myLimit};
    this.props.updateLimit(lim)
    
// this part does not work
// function open Modal for 1,5 second like "Success"
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: true
    });
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        modalOpen: false
      })
    }, 1500);
// this works
// this sends update state for toggle in Parent component
    this.props.changeToggle(false);
  }   
render(){   
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       //some code
        <Button onPress={this.combineFunc} title='submit' /> 
      </View> 
    )
  }
```

But in this case it does not change -> `this.setState({modalOpen: true})` and Modal does not open at all.
Why does it happen? Is it possible to set some order to run?
I think the problem is in `setTimeout`, but I need it for a popup.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what isn't working? Is the state not updating? Is the timeout not working as expected? Is this all working but `this.state.modalOpen` isn't working as expected (presumably as a passed prop)? Something else? Perhaps also provide some context around what `props.updateLimit` and `props.changeToggle` do and if/how they relate to *this* component.

Comment: Hi Drew, I've added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao the problem is in setTimeout as you said. You know `this.setState` is async. But it has a callback, so try this:

```
this.setState({
  modalOpen: true
}, () => {
   this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
     this.setState({
       modalOpen: false
     })
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: even if I leave only `this.setState({ modalOpen: true})` it still doesn't open Modal

Comment: Ok, from your example I don't undestand where is Modal. Is in child or in Parent?

Comment: it's in child `<MyPopup visible={this.state.modalOpen}>`

Comment: Thanks for question update. Your code is simple and clear.  So, could be only a problem with MyPopup component. Have you checked that in MyPopup you passed visible props to Modal in a correct way?

Comment: yes for sure, because it works in first case, but does not in the second

Comment: Ciao, I reproduced what you want to do [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modal-i1j1m?file=/index.js). As you can see, I'm using my solution and it works! That's the reason why I think the problme should be elsewhere...

Comment: If you want, make a codesandbox with your code and I could continue to help you.

Comment: thank you very much Giovanni! it's quite complex solution with Redux, I will try to fix it myself. Thanks again!